# cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so.dpkg-new'

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04

Whenever I run `sudo apt install python3-pip`, it shows

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get:

```
error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-va-drivers_20.0.8-0u
buntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_vide
o.so' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so.dpkg-new': unexpect
ed end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-va-drivers_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What could be the issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you run out of hard drive space at some point? It looks like you maybe either are running out of HDD space or ran out of it at some point.  Try running `sudo apt clean && sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Brian Turek, No, I did not but there was a fsck error /dev/sda5 but I fixed it and I tried the command and it worked thanks a lot!